# Changed a table name in MySql => error in symfony code

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I changed a table name from 'match' to 'matchGame'. Then I edited all of my code so that matchGame was used everywhere. I then used the commands doctrine:import and generate:entities to update all the things for the database. However if I run my program now I get following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Tactic  
  s::setMatchMatchid() must be an instance of Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Match,  
   instance of Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Matchgame given, called in C:\wamp\ww  
  w\SocProNetbeans\src\Login\LoginBundle\Command\CreateSeasonCommand.php on l  
  ine 73 and defined in C:\wamp\www\SocProNetbeans\src\Login\LoginBundle\Enti  
  ty\Tactics.php line 632
```

What adjustment do I need to do to change this?

Comment: i think you fail in your massive replace , check classname on your file Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Match

Comment: I deleted that file and generated a new one

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've not changed the name of your Match entity class.

Comment: Found the problem, I didn't change the name in the tactic entity class file, it is resolved now.